# Error response in ember-data api

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My code for saving document to API looks like that

```
    save(category) {
        category.save().then(() => {
            this.transitionTo('categories');
        }).catch((adapterError) => {
            console.log(category.get('errors').toArray());
            console.log(category.get('isValid'));
        });
    },
```

When API answers is:

> {"errors":[{"attribute":"name","message":"This value should not be blank."}]}

then

> category.get('isValid')

still returns true.

My question is, how validation errors should looks like?

Comment: What are the headers of the request from the developer console when you save the object?

Comment: Before I had 200, but now change to 400, results is the same.

Comment: Error handling depends on your ember-data adapter. Which adapter are you using?

Comment: I'm using JSONAPIAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ember-data's adapter determines that a response is invalid when the status code is 422. You can override the `isInvalid` function of the adapter to change this.

Also, ember-data now expects errors to be formatted into a json-api error object. If your backend doesn't return it in this format, you can transform it in ember by overriding the `handleResponse` function of the adapter.

This is a sample json-api error:

```
{"errors": [
  {
    "detail": "Must be unique",
    "source": { pointer: "/data/attributes/title"}
  },
  {
    "detail": "Must not be blank",
    "source": { pointer: "/data/attributes/content"}
  }
]}
```

If you're returning error responses you described above, you would have to do something like this in your adapter:

```
handleResponse(status, headers, payload) {                                                                                                                                                                                               
  if (status === 422 && payload.errors) {                                                                                                                                                                                                
    let jsonApiErrors = [];                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    for (let key in payload.errors) {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      for (let i = 0; i < payload.errors[key].length; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                             
        jsonApiErrors.push({                                                                                                                                                                                                             
          detail: payload.errors[key][i],                                                                                                                                                                                                
          source: {                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            pointer: `data/attributes/${key}`                                                                                                                                                                                            
          }                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        });                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

    return new DS.InvalidError(jsonApiErrors);                                                                                                                                                                                           
  } else {                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return this._super(...arguments);                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
}
```